# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'FileTypeModule' was called

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

trying to setup [ngx-formly-material-file](https://github.com/alEX860111/ngx-formly-material-file), but I got an error: 
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'FileTypeModule' was called

I tried to export FileTypeModule, but got the same error

```
export const fileTypeModule = FileTypeModule.forRoot();

@NgModule({
  imports: [fileTypeModule]

})
```

Answer (score 38):

Have seen this happening many times, last time, with Angular 9, happened during `ng build <my-library>`, for all modules that were initialized with `forRoot`

I added in `tsconfig.lib.json` this and the error went away.

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  }
```

The `fullTemplateTypeCheck` compiler switch actually enables the binding expression validation phase of the template compiler. See more details [here](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#fulltemplatetypecheck).

Comment: Works for me too!!

Answer (score 5):

> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'FileTypeModule' was called

I don't have good news about this error message.

It is an issue with Angular 8.2.x and up that introduced limitations on how you can generate metadata for `NgModule` that are side effects from recent updates to support Ivy.

```
export const fileTypeModule = FileTypeModule.forRoot();
```

The only way to fix this error is to modify the function `forRoot()` from the module. There are strict limitations on what can be done inside that function.

You can not dynamically generate any providers, use arrow functions or conditionally create a `NgModule` metadata.

This error has a long history now across multiple libraries:

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/727

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609

You can find my specific ways of fixing this problem here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609#issuecomment-561615821

If you are not the author for the `FileTypeModule` the only work around is to contact the author and request that they fix the problem, or you fork the library and make the fixes yourself.